# How to add swift package with binary target as dependency in a second target

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I added a Swift Package that has a single binary target to my SwiftUI app.

https://github.com/persona-id/inquiry-ios-2

It works fine in my main iOS app target. I added a second iOS app target in my Xcode project, and I can't add the Swift package there as a dependency. It doesn't show up in the search. It appears like this in my main target in the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section.

[image]

How do I add this Swift package to a second iOS app target in my project?